# Alias Rails Model with Scope as different class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I have a rails model with a scope that I would like to be able to use as a separate class for future semantics consistency. An example of this would be -

```
class User
  scope :admin, => { where(admin: true) }
end
```

For my purposes, it's important that documentation and code is clearer than calling User.admin whenever I want to work with just admins, without creating a separate model. (Schema is identical, and there is more than 1 scope I need to move into a separate object).

My current solution is

```
class Admin
  @@receiver = User.admin

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    @@receiver.send(m, *args, &block)
  end

  def self.method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    @@receiver.send(m, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

This way, I can use `Admin` as an `ActiveRecord::Relation` where ever I need.

Is this an effective means of solving the issue? Because of gems we're running, I cannot inherit User, or it will start using STI and get really weird really quickly.

Comment: I don't think efficiency is really going to be the issue here - its going to be debugging/overall buggyness and the fact that basic stuff like `respond_to?` won't work for this class so you can't use duck typing.

Comment: If you don't want to use STI I can think of better alternatives like putting all the shared fucntionality into a base class (BaseUser) and making it abstract or moving all the shared functionality into modules. If you still just want to do delegation Ruby has much better ways such as DelegateClass, Forwardable and Delegator.

Comment: @max oooh, good point. I did end up finding [the rails delegate_missing_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate_missing_to) method, which I think solves for my issue better. I do appreciate your other points, but this isn't a standard abstraction type - thing, there isn't additional functionality I'd like to extend with Admin. It's just a matter of semantics for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach would be to create `Admin` as a subclass of `User` with a [default_scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class).

```
 class Admin < User
    def self.default_scope
        admin
    end
    #...
 end
```

Comment: yeah, that's correct!